# The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context(c#,xamarin)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I just downloaded Visual Studio and created a new Xamarin.Forms project. However, when building the app with the auto-generated code I got stuck on the following error in the code-behind of MainPage.xaml:

`The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context`

I looked up solutions on the internet but did not find one that works for me.
What I tried:

- Changing the custom tool in the properties of MainPage.xaml (which was empty beforehand)
- I checked if the namespaces match (they do)
- I tried saving all the files

Here is an image of the auto-generated code, which I didn't edit:
[image: MainPage.xaml and MainPage.xaml.cs]

Comment: are you sure the namespace of the code behind and the xaml are the same?

Comment: "solutions didn't work for me" - you need to tell us what you've tried, otherwise we'll just waste our time suggesting things you might have already done.  Like verifying that all of the packages have been restored.

Comment: Did you change any namespaces?

Comment: Yeah, that's my vote as well.  You have a naming problem.

Comment: A naming problem ! how could it be ? in the picture the namspace is App6 in code behind file and in the xaml file the App6 is refrenced in x:Class="App6.MainPage"

Comment: I've had this issue crop up here and there. Not sure of the underlying problem, but if it is the same as I've had, I unload and reload all projects. It seems to work, but that's only if there isn't a more fundamental problem going on. YMMV

Comment: I don't feel confident posting that as an answer since I can't really give any other information or be confident this is the solution, but if it works for you, let me know and I'll post it as an answer

Comment: @TimothyJames It really worked post the answer for me to mark it as a solution thanks it worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had this issue crop up here and there where `InitializeComponent` and a number of other classes and methods "does not exist in the current context". Not sure of the underlying problem, but if it is the same as I've had, I unload and reload all projects. This can be accomplished by right clicking on the project in the solution explorer, clicking unload, right clicking again, and hitting reload.

Comment: This worked for me on visual studio for mac 2019

Comment: This worked for me also - VS2022

Answer (score 5):

If you are having successful builds, but a nagging initializecomponent does not exist error,

CLOSE VS,
DELETE the hidden .vs folder in your project (this clears intellisense).
OPEN VS - the error is gone.

Comment: the accepted answer does not work for me, yours @pollaris works for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had also this problem sometimes when creating a new page, make sure that the BuildAction of the page is set to "Embedded resource" as other normal pages
[image]

Comment: Out of all answers, this one worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to remove the error on my Xamarin project. I closed the project and removed obj folders. Then reloaded the Project again and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Check the ContentPage property of your XAML file. Make sure that the x:Class value, is correct, example: x:Class="YourProjectName.Views.ContentPageName">

I created a ContentPage and then renamed it, but the x:Class wasn't updated, so I had to do it manually. Tried first unload/reload but didn't work in my case.

In one case also, I created a content page with the name 'Buttons' and had the same issue. I deleted it and created another one with the name 'UsingButtons' and was ok. Maybe there are reserved words for file names.